# How to define such a command with an optional argument in my class?

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

I'm preparing a document class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\@mypic}[1]{%
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{pic1}
}

\newcommand{\mytitlepage}{
\begin{center}
Title 

\@mypic


Jan 2015
\end{center}
}
```

And this is my root file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\end{document}
```

My problem is with the `\@mypic` command. I want this command to load the `pic1` figure by default, but also I want that my users be able to load their figure in the preamble, if they don't like the default figure. In other words, I want this: If they enter a command like `\mypic[.6]{pic3}` in the preamble, the `pic3` substitute for the `pic1` with `.6\textwidth`.
**How can I do this?**

### Edit (More clear explanation):

I want this:
If my users don't like the default figure and its width, they can change both the figure and its width. I think this problem has a simple solution.
BTW, it would be better the solution use only latex core, not using packages like `xparse`.

Comment: Should just the file name be optional or the width as well? Do you want a single command to set this data or can we use two separate ones (_e.g._ `\titlepicture` and `\titlepicturewidth` or similar)?

Comment: @JosephWright: please see my Edit above. I just want my users to be able to use their figure and their desired width.

Comment: @Sisabe I added a version of `sisabe.cls` that uses only features already loaded by `graphicx`. You lose much flexibility, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a key-value syntax, for example the one provided by `expl3`:

### File `sisabe.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sisabeclass}
\LoadClass{book}

\RequirePackage{graphicx,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitlepage}{ O{} }
 {
  \begin{center}
  \keys_set:nn { sisabeclass / titlepage } { #1 }
  \g_sisabe_titlepage_title_tl
  \par
  \vspace{1cm} % adjust
  \sisabe_titlepage_picture:VV \l_sisabe_titlepage_picoptions_tl \l_sisabe_titlepage_picture_tl
  \par
  \vspace{1cm} % adjust
  \g_sisabe_titlepage_date_tl
  \end{center}
 }

\keys_define:nn { sisabeclass / titlepage }
 {
  title   .tl_gset:N = \g_sisabe_titlepage_title_tl,
  title   .initial:n = MISSING TITLE,
  date    .tl_gset:N = \g_sisabe_titlepage_date_tl,
  date    .initial:n = MISSING DATE,
  options .tl_set:N  = \l_sisabe_titlepage_picoptions_tl,
  options .initial:n = { width=.3\textwidth },
  picture .tl_set:N  = \l_sisabe_titlepage_picture_tl,
  picture .initial:n = { example-image.pdf }, % adjust
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sisabe_titlepage_picture:nn #1 #2
 {
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sisabe_titlepage_picture:nn { VV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\endinput
```

### File `test.tex`

```
\documentclass{sisabe}

\begin{document}

\mytitlepage

\hrule

\mytitlepage[
  title = A wonderful paper,
  date = January 2015,
  picture = example-image-9x16.pdf,
  options = {height=4cm},
]

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

### File `sisabe.cls` that only uses features already loaded by `graphicx`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sisabeclass}
\LoadClass{book}

\RequirePackage{graphicx} % already loads keyval

\newcommand{\mytitlepage}[1][]{%
  \begin{center}
  \setkeys{sisabetitle}{#1}
  \sisabetitlepage@title
  \par
  \vspace{1cm} % adjust
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\includegraphics[\sisabetitlepage@picoptions]{\sisabetitlepage@picture}%
  }\x
  \par
  \vspace{1cm} % adjust
  \sisabetitlepage@date
  \end{center}
 }

\define@key{sisabetitle}{title}{\gdef\sisabetitlepage@title{#1}}
\define@key{sisabetitle}{date}{\gdef\sisabetitlepage@date{#1}}
\define@key{sisabetitle}{options}{\def\sisabetitlepage@picoptions{#1}}
\define@key{sisabetitle}{picture}{\def\sisabetitlepage@picture{#1}}
\setkeys{sisabetitle}{%
  title=MISSING TITLE,
  date=MISSING DATE,
  options={width=.3\textwidth},
  picture={example-image.pdf},% adjust
 }
\endinput
```

The output with the same test file is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

This provides two possible ways to define the command with some optional argument -- the classical `\newcommand` style and with `\NewDocumentCommand`. If the optional argument is omitted, the `pic1` is used,otherwise the value of #1 as optional argument.

More configurability could be achieved with a key-value interface.

Class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\@mypic}[1]{%
  \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{#1}%
}




\newcommand{\mytitlepage}[1][pic1]{
\begin{center}
Title  

\@mypic{#1}%


Jan 2015
\end{center}
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\MyTitlePage}{+O{pic1}}{%
\begin{center}
Title NewDocumentCommand-like 

\@mypic{#1}

\today
\end{center}
}%
```

Document:

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\mytitlepage[bild_erwin_schroedinger]

\MyTitlePage[bild_erwin_schroedinger]

\MyTitlePage
\end{document}
```

Comment: And what about the figure width? I want my users can change the both figure and its width (see my Edit above).

Comment: @Sisabe: I've written in my solution that a better approach would be a `key-value` version, but I had no time this afternoon to implement this. In the meantime, egreg provided such a solution, so it's not really useful to update my solution, unless you 'insist'

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with a standard class, but you can implement these macros into your class.  I make `\mytitlepage` have two optional arguments.  The first must be the resize and the second is the image replacement.

So, if you want a new image, you must specify the size fraction argument.  However, I have EDITED the answer so that a blank first optional argument, as in `\mytitlepage[][example-image-B]` will retain the default size of `.3\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@mypic}[2]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}}
\newcommand{\mytitlepage}[1][.3]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\def\figwidth{.3}\else\def\figwidth{#1}\fi%
  \mytitlepagehelp}
\newcommand{\mytitlepagehelp}[1][example-image-A]{%
\begin{center}
Title\par
\@mypic{\figwidth}{#1}\par
Jan 2015
\end{center}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mytitlepage
\mytitlepage[.4]
\mytitlepage[.4][example-image-B]
\mytitlepage[][example-image-C]
\end{document}
```

[image]